# Unable to navigate from a custom navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

So I've a custom navigator which I use for swipe back navigation.
Also, I apologize for posting images and not pasting the code for some genuine reasons. I hope you check out the images.

Below is the code for the custom navigator.
https://gist.github.com/shubham6996/985568f49b2511dec2438c624fe259d0

```
const SwipeMainStack = () => {
    return(
        <Navigator>
            <Route name="LoggedOutHome" component={LoggedOutHome} />
            <Route name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
            <Route name="EmailAuth" component={EmailAuth} />
            <Route name="Login" component={Login} />
            <Route name="EmailLogin" component={EmailLogin} />
            <Route name="EmailSignUp" component={EmailSignUp} />
            <Route name="SignupUsername" component={SignupUsername} />
        </Navigator> 
    );
}

const stack = createStackNavigator({
    SwipeStack: {screen: SwipeMainStack},
    TabHolder: {screen: TabHolder},
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'SwipeStack',
    headerMode: 'none',
});

export default createAppContainer(stack);
```

Below is the LoggedOutHome Screen
[image]

Below is the SignUp Screen
[image]

Below is the EmailSignUp Screen
[image]

Below is the EmailLogin Screen
[image]

So how my navigation works is, when I navigate to `SignUp` screen, it takes me to the `EmailSignUp` which then takes me to the `EmailAuth`.

I'm able to navigate from `LoggedOutHome` to `EmailAuth` Screen using `this.props.navigator.push('SignUp')` but I'm not able to navigate from `EmailAuth` to `SignUp`

Answer (score 0):

If you define your SwipeMainStack like below then it should work.

```
const SwipeMainStack = createStackNavigator({
    LoggedOutHome: LoggedOutHome,
    SignUp: SignUp,
    EmailAuth:EmailAuth
    Login:Login
    EmailLogin:EmailLogin
    EmailSignUp:EmailSignUp
    SignupUsername:SignupUsername

})



const stack = createStackNavigator({
    SwipeStack: SwipeMainStack
    TabHolder: TabHolder,
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'SwipeStack',
    headerMode: 'none',
});

export default createAppContainer(stack);
```

Comment: actually I'm using custom navigation. According to your answer, it would have worked. But I've a different scenario.

Comment: Ok. I will look at your GitHub repo and I will update you.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know.